# Magento Fatal error: website/app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 37

Tags: magento

```
Magento fatal error Fatal error: Class 
'Mage_Dataflow_Model_Convert_Container_Abstract' not found in
/home/magento/public_html/website/app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 37
```

I am showing this fatal error in my index management and everywhere when i save anything.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error log it seems that **Mage_Dataflow_Model_Convert_Container_Abstract** class cannot be found.

If you see the **Abstract.php** file in **Mage_Dataflow_Model_Convert_Adapter_Abstract** you can see in line 37 it is extending **Mage_Dataflow_Model_Convert_Container_Abstract**.So check whether this file presents in

> app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Container

folder.

This could be the issue.

Hope it works.